# Prove that $x \equiv 0$ of $\dot{x}(t)=a(t)x$ is Uniformly Asymptotically Stable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory

I have a problem:

> Consider the scalar equation: $$\dot{x}(t)=a(t)x \tag{I}$$ where $a(t) \in C(\mathbb{R}^+)$.
>
> Prove that $x \equiv 0$ of $(I)$  is **Uniformly Asymptotically
>   Stable** iff $$\forall M>0, \exists T>0, \forall t_0 \ge 0:
>  \int_{t_0}^{t}a(s)\mathrm{d}s<-M, \forall t \ge t_0+T$$

**Here's my sketch:**

- The first, since the equation $\dot{x}(t)=a(t)x $, we have $$x(t)=x_0 \cdot \exp  \left (\int_{t_0}^{t}a(s)\mathrm{d}s \right)$$
- The second, $\forall M>0, \exists T>0, \forall t_0 \ge 0: \int_{t_0}^{t}a(s)\mathrm{d}s<-M \iff \exp  \left (\int_{t_0}^{t}a(s)\mathrm{d}s \right) < e^{-M} $

Thus, $$\left|x(t) \right|=\left|x_0  \cdot \exp  \left (\int_{t_0}^{t}a(s)\mathrm{d}s \right) \right| \le \left|x_0 \right|  \cdot \exp  \left (\int_{t_0}^{t}a(s)\mathrm{d}s \right) \le  \left|x_0 \right| e^{-M}$$

- Now, I have stuck when I'm trying to show that  $x \equiv 0$ of $(I)$ is **Uniformly Stable** and **Uniformly convergent**, we know

$1/$ **Uniformly convergent**:

$\forall \epsilon >0,\exists \delta_1>0, \exists T=T(\epsilon)>0, \text{s.t}: \|x(t_0)\|<\delta_1 \implies \|x(t)\|< \epsilon, \forall t \ge t_0 +T$.

$2/$ **Uniformly Stable**:

$\forall \epsilon >0,\exists \delta = \delta (\epsilon)>0, \text{s.t}: \|x(t_0)\|<\delta \implies \|x(t)\|< \epsilon, \forall t \ge t_0 \ge 0$.

======================================

I choose $\epsilon = \left|x_0 \right| e^{-M}>0$. But **How** do we find $T=T(\epsilon)=???$

Whence, I still have no solution.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to refine your definitions for uniformly convergent and uniformly stable: Is $t_0$ fixed, or is it that for any $t_0$ and $\varepsilon$ you can find a $\delta$ that might depend on $t_0$ such that..., or is that for any $t_0$ and $\varepsilon$ you can find a $\delta$ that is **independent** of $t_0$ such that .... Typically (as far as I can tell) definitions of uniform convergence involve the latter case.

Comment: And can you find $T$, **jkn**?

Comment: In my textbook: http://g10.picoodle.com/ltd/img10/5/10/2/kimtahe6/f_1_2ba_udizb.jpg Can you read? Plz

Comment: @ **jkn** : I'm sorry because I didn't see your reply. Hihi :) . I'll try to fix and clarify my questions and make my post clearer. Thank for your reply, and for taking the time to think about my problems. It's great! (y) In the future, if it's n't disturbance then I'm looking forward to your helps. I'm very pleased to get acquainted with you. **jkn**. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: The definition you linked says the "equilibrium $x_e=0$ at $t_0$ of $\dot{x}=f(x,t)$" which seems to imply that we are only interested in a particular fixed initial time $t_0$. I'm just going to roll with that: In the answer I assume that *$t_0$ is some fixed initial time*. However, it seems a bit strange given that the terminology "uniformly stable" and "uniformly convergent" which, in my experience, usually involves making statements for all possible times $t_0$ (see, for example, [the book by Khalil](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130673897)).

To get the if we first show that

$$\forall M>0, \exists T>0:\int_{t_0}^{t}a(s)\mathrm{d}s<-M, \forall t \ge t_0+T\quad\quad(*)$$

implies that $0$ is uniformly asymptotically stable. Then, to get the only if it is enough to show that $0$ being uniformly convergent implies $(*)$.

To show that $(*)$ implies that $0$ is uniformly asymptotically stable we have show that $(*)$ implies that $0$ is both uniformly convergent and uniformly stable.

---

Uniformly convergent is easy. Fix any $\varepsilon>0$. Then, require that there exists a $\delta>0$ and $T>0$ such that

$$|x(t_0)|\leq \delta\Rightarrow |x(t)|\leq \varepsilon\quad\forall t\geq t_0+T.$$

Fix any $M>0$. From your sketch we have that there exists a $T>0$ such that

$$\left|x(t) \right|\leq \left|x(t_0) \right| e^{-M}$$

for all $t\geq t_0+T$. Picking $\delta=\varepsilon e^M$ then gives us the desired $|x(t)|\leq\varepsilon$ for all $t\geq t_0+T$.

---

For uniform stability: Again pick any $M>0$ and let $T>0$ be such that

$$|x(t)|\leq |x(t_0)|e^{-M} \quad (**)$$

for all $t\geq t_0+T$. Since $a$ is continuous, it is easy to see that

$$\int_{t_0}^{t_0+T}a(s)ds\leq \alpha$$

for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, for any $t\in[t_0,t_0+T]$,

$$|x(t)|=|x(t_0)|\left|exp\left(\int_{t_0}^{t_0+T}a(s)ds\right)\right|\leq |x(t_0)|e^\alpha. \quad (***)$$

So, if we set $\delta=\min\{\varepsilon e^M,\varepsilon e^{-\alpha}\}$, then $(**)$ and $(***)$ gives the desired $|x(t)|\leq \varepsilon$ for all $t\geq t_0$.

---

Lastly, for the only if: By uniform convergence you have that for any $x(t_0)$

$$\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t)=\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t_0)\exp\left(\int_{t_0}^{t}a(s)ds\right)=0\Leftrightarrow \lim_{t\to\infty} \int_{t_0}^{t}a(s)ds=0$$

which is equivalent to $(*)$.

Comment: I accepted your ANS! Thanks! **jkn**

Answer (score 1):

**Here's another solution:**

1/ We'll show that $x \equiv 0$ is **Uniformly Stable** iff $$\int_{t_0}^{t}a(s)\mathrm{d}s \le M, \forall t \ge t_0 \ge 0$$

- Proof (**Sufficiency**).

We assume that $x \equiv 0$ is **Uniformly Stable**.
$\forall \epsilon >0, \forall t_0 \ge 0 ,\exists \delta=\delta(\epsilon)>0 $ such that $$\|x_0\|< \delta \implies \|x(t)\| < \epsilon, \forall t \ge t_0 \ge 0$$
Taking $t_0=0,x_0=\dfrac{\delta}{2}, \epsilon =1$. So:
$$\|x(t;0;x_0)\|=|x_0|\exp\left(\int_{0}^{t}a(s)\mathrm{d}s \right) <\epsilon =1$$
Therefore, $\int_{0}^{t}a(s)\mathrm{d}s< M:=\log\left(\dfrac{2}{\delta} \right)$.

- Proof (**Necesity**).

We assume that $\int_{t_0}^{t}a(s)\mathrm{d}s \le M, \forall t \ge t_0 \ge 0 $

We have $\forall \epsilon >0, \forall t_0 \ge 0 ,\exists \delta=\delta(\epsilon)>0 $ such that $\|x_0\|< \delta$.

We consider $\|x(t)\| \le  \epsilon:=\delta \exp \left(-\int_{0}^{t_0}a(s)\mathrm{d}s \right) e^M, \forall t \ge t_0 \ge 0$

2/ We'll show that $x \equiv 0$ is **Asymptotically Stable** iff $$\lim_{t \to \infty}\int_{t_0}^{t}a(s)\mathrm{d}s =-\infty $$

3/ Since $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have $x \equiv 0$ is **Uniformly Asymptotically Stable** if and only if $$\forall M>0, \exists T>0, \forall t_0 \ge 0:
 \int_{t_0}^{t}a(s)\mathrm{d}s<-M, \forall t \ge t_0+T$$.