# Show that $\dot{x}(t)=a(t)x$ Uniformly Stable when $a(t)\in C(t_0,\infty)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

> Consider the scalar equation $$\dot{x}(t)=a(t)x(t)$$ which is stable and reducible.

I'm trying to show that $\dot{x}(t)=a(t)x(t)$ is uniformly stable when $a(t)\in C(t_0,\infty)$.

> The precise definition for [uniformaly stable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/511834/1190476). $$\forall \epsilon >0,\exists \delta = \delta (\epsilon)>0, \text{s.t}: \|x(t_0)\|<\delta \implies \|x(t)\|< \epsilon, \forall t \ge t_0 \ge 0$$

I want to use it to solve my problem. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Seems true when $a(t)≤0$ for all $t$, since in that case $∫_{t_0}^t a(u) \geq ∫_{t_0}^{t'} a(u)$ for all $t′>t$ and hence u have uniform stability. Are u claiming your statement is true even when for some $t$ , $a(t)>0$ ?

Answer (score 0):

By separation of variables, for the solution
$$x'/x = a \longrightarrow x(t)\ \to\ \text {x0}  \  e^{\int_{t_0}^t a(\tau) d\tau} $$
remains to show
$$\forall \varepsilon>0  \ \  \exists \delta>0  \  \ \text{s.t} \ \ ||x_0|| < \delta \ \implies   \ e^{\int_{t_0}^t a(\tau) d\tau}  <  e^{\max_{t_0,t}(a)(t-t_0)} <  \varepsilon $$